# tensorflow deeplabv3+ train from scratch train.sh code to recurring 82.2% in VOC val

Tags: python, tensorflow

DATA: VOC 2012 augmented datasets: I am training [train_aug](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sun11/2dbda6b31acc7c6292d14a872d0c90b7/raw/5f5a5270089239ef2f6b65b1cc55208355b5acca/trainaug.txt) with 10582 [annotations](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oeu149j8qtbs1x0/SegmentationClassAug.zip?dl=0&file_subpath=%2FSegmentationClassAug).

CODE: I am using official deeplabv3+ [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab).**I didn't change the code** except bash code.

Pretrained weight: xception_65_imagenet_coco from [official zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md)

So, this is my train.sh:

```
python "${WORK_DIR}"/train.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --train_split="train_aug" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --train_crop_size="513,513" \
  --train_batch_size=15 \
  --training_number_of_steps=30000 \
  --fine_tune_batch_norm=False \
  --num_clones=5 \
  --base_learning_rate=0.007 \
  --tf_initial_checkpoint="${COCO_PRE}/x65-b2u1s2p-d48-2-3x256-sc-cr300k_init.ckpt" \
  --train_logdir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}" \
  --dataset_dir="${PASCAL_DATASET}"\
  --initialize_last_layer=False
```

Result: I think it should be 82.2% with my configuration.But I got 80%on eval.OS=16 and 80.15% on eval.OS=8 in 30k steps

[image: train loss]

So my question is : How can I get 82.2%?

edit:09.02.2019:-----------------

I have notice that the `fine_tune_batch_norm=false`.

and in train.py:

> Set to True if one wants to fine-tune the batch norm parameters in
>   DeepLabv3

So I decide to try `fine_tune_batch_norm=true` cause training from scratch need to change the BN parameters. 
edit------09/07--------------------
Still not working with:

```
python "${WORK_DIR}"/train.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --train_split="train_aug" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --train_crop_size="513,513" \
  --train_batch_size=15 \
  --training_number_of_steps=100000 \
  --fine_tune_batch_norm=true \
  --num_clones=5 \
  --base_learning_rate=0.007 \
  --tf_initial_checkpoint="${COCO_PRE}/x65-b2u1s2p-d48-2-3x256-sc-cr300k_init.ckpt" \
  --train_logdir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}" \
  --dataset_dir="${PASCAL_DATASET}"\
  --initialize_last_layer=False
```

This time the result is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduce the result. I got 81.5%. I use 40000 steps for the first round, I think 30000 steps might better.

Bash Code:

```
python "${WORK_DIR}"/train.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --train_split="train_aug" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --train_crop_size="513,513" \
  --train_batch_size=24 \
  --base_learning_rate=0.007 \
  --training_number_of_steps=30000 \
  --fine_tune_batch_norm=true \
  --num_clones=8 \
  --tf_initial_checkpoint="${COCO_PRE}/x65-b2u1s2p-d48-2-3x256-sc-cr300k_init.ckpt" \
  --train_logdir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}" \
  --dataset_dir="${PASCAL_DATASET}"\
  --initialize_last_layer=true

python "${WORK_DIR}"/train.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --train_split="train" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --train_crop_size="513,513" \
  --train_batch_size=24 \
  --training_number_of_steps=60000 \
  --fine_tune_batch_norm=false \
  --num_clones=8 \
  --base_learning_rate=0.01 \
  --tf_initial_checkpoint="${COCO_PRE}/x65-b2u1s2p-d48-2-3x256-sc-cr300k_init.ckpt" \
  --train_logdir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}" \
  --dataset_dir="${PASCAL_DATASET}"\
  --initialize_last_layer=true
```

reference: [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5116)